# Ember cannot set attribute using set method

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have my custom Ember Component class and am trying to reset some attribute values

```
formData: Ember.Object.create({}),
resetformData: function() {
    this.formData.attr1 = "";
    this.formData.attr2 = ""; // This works 

        //All the below syntax are not working
        this.formData.set('attr1', "");
        this.formData.set('attr2', "");
        this.set('formData', Ember.Object.create({
            attr1: "",
            attr2: ""           
        }));
        this.set('formData', {
            attr1: "",
            attr2: ""           
        });

},
```

Now when I call this.resetformData(), 
I cannot get the attributes to reset using the "set" method syntax.

Comment: `this.set('formData.attr1', "");`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Ember.set` method if you really want to use other syntax:

```
Ember.set(this, 'formData.attr1', '');
```

Comment: please use `Ember.set(this, 'formData.attr1', '');`, because only this works for chains of Computed Properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What exactly do you mean by chain of computed properties and why does this.set does not work ?